# For Each object in List, create a producer and consumer in rabbitmq using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, rabbitmq, microservices

basically I am wanting to create and destroy queues and consumers dynamically at runtime based on the sensor list. I have added code that only works sorta. I am hoping someone with more experience can help me figure out how to do what I want to do with a bunch of sensors and agents monitoring the sensors.

```
  public class SensorQueueConsumer
    {
        public static void Consume(IModel channel)
        {
            Tasks.AddData();
            foreach (string sensor in Sensor.SensorList)
            {

                channel.QueueDeclare($"{sensor}Queue",
            durable: true,
            exclusive: false,
            autoDelete: false,
            arguments: null);
                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                consumer.Received += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var body = e.Body.ToArray();
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                };

                channel.BasicConsume($"{sensor}Queue", true, consumer);
                Console.WriteLine("consumer started");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

and

```
 public static class SensorQueueProducer
    {
        public static void Publish(IModel channel)
        {Tasks.AddData();
            foreach (string sensor in Sensor.SensorList)
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare($"{sensor}Queue",
            durable: true,
            exclusive: false,
            autoDelete: false,
            arguments: null);
                var Count = 0;
                while (true)
                {
                    var message = new { Name = "PlantEvent", Sensor = sensor, Saverity = "high", Message = $"Hello! Water me!! Count:{Count}" };
                    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));

                    channel.BasicPublish("", $"{sensor}Queue", null, body);
                    Count++;
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

and also the sensor class the list

```
public class Sensor
    {
        public static List<String> SensorList { get; set; } = new List<String>();

    }
    public class Tasks
    {
        public static void AddData()
        {
            string[] sensors = { "ec", "soil", "co2" };
            Sensor.SensorList.AddRange(sensors);

        }

        public static void ClearData()
        {
            Sensor.SensorList.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have a list of objects that I want to create a set of consumers and producers with in rabbit mq. Essentially for each object in objectlist create a producer and consumer. In my application i have users enter their sensors to a table, that table generates to a list and based on the lists it will create what it needs to view the data on an event bus in rabitmq

Comment: basically I am wanting to create and destroy queues and consumers dynamically at runtime based on the sensor list. I have added code that only works sorta. I am hoping someone with more experience can help me figure out how to do what I want to do with a bunch of sensors and agents monitoring the sensors.

Comment: @Adam you can edit the question and add this additional information inside.

Comment: @theodor will that help get an answer as to why I can only get 1 or 2 queues to run?

Comment: @Adam it might help, but there are no guarantees. In general the more appetizing is a question, the more likely to get answers. If people, after reading a long question, they are still not sure what the question is all about, they might lose their patience and move on.